# Sharing news links

Tags: android, android-sharing

I have a problem of how to implement a way of sharing a news link that when the receiver of the link click on it, the link should take them to the news details activity in my app if the user does not have my app installed on their phones the link should take them to google play page.

**Note:**

I don't want my users to be routed to any website and
my app has a list of news activity and activity for displaying single news details.

Comment: what have you tried far?

Comment: I have read about **Firebase** feature called **Dynamic link** but I still confused because I searched a lot and haven't seen anyone doing this or similar  to this